# dmlx XGBoost job stuck in Yarn in "ACCEPTED" state when submitted subsequently

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, xgboost

I have a 3 node cluster in AWS ( 1 Master and 2 slaves)

Configurations :
master ( 8 vCPU, 16 GB)
slave1 (4 vCPU, 8 GB)
slave1 (4 vCPU, 8 GB)

when i submit a dmlc-xgboost job to yarn it run as expected but if i submit the same job again with in 5 mins it gets stuck.
If jobs are submitted in a succession of 6 mins or so it works perfectly alright.

I tried to check in yarn the reason for getting stuck and it says something like below

> [Sun Jun 09 09:03:53 +0000 2019] Application is added to the scheduler
>   and is not yet activated.  **Queues AM resource limit exceeded**.  Details
>   : AM Partition = ;  AM Resource Request =
>   ;  Queue Resource Limit for AM = ;  User AM Resource Limit of the queue = ; Queue AM Resource Usage = ;

tried modifying yarn parameters after reading all he threads in the internet but havnt got any luck yet.

Below are my configurations I am using currently.

**capacity-scheduler.xml**

yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications  : 10000
yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent : 0.9
yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator  : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator 
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues     :  default

**yarn-site.xml**

yarn.acl.enable : 0
yarn.resourcemanager.hostname : node-master
yarn.nodemanager.aux-services  : mapreduce_shuffle
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb : 4608
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb : 4608
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb : 1536
yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled : false
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb : 3072

**mapred-site.xml**

mapreduce.framework.name : yarn
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb : 1536
mapreduce.map.memory.mb : 1536
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb : 3072

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might be getting live-locked.  What does the YARN UI show when you hit this state?

Comment: yarn state says "UNDEFINED" and stuck there forever until killed explicitly.

Comment: There is no way to tell you're live-locked unless you provide the cluster capacity and current usage/running state (the info in the YARN UI).